# Prove whether $([0,1),*)$ is group or not, where $x*y=\begin{cases}x+y &: x+y<1\\ x+y-1 &:x+y \ge 1.\end{cases}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Problem. Given a nonempty set $G=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} | 0 \leq x < 1\rbrace$. Let * be a binary operation on $G$ that defined below.

(i) $x*y = x+y,$ if $x+y<1$.

(ii) $x*y=x+y-1,$ if $x+y \geq 1$.

Is $G$ a group?

Here my solution so far. Please correct it clearly.

(i) If $x+y<1$, then $x*y=x+y$.
We will show that $*$ is assosiative. Let $a,b,c \in G$. We'll show that $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$. Now,
$(a*b)*c=(a+b)*c = (a+b)+c=a+(b+c)=a*(b+c)=a*(b*c)$ Hence, $*$ is assosiative.

Now, $0 \in G$. Let $a \in G$, then
$0*a=0+a=a=a+0=a*0$. Hence, $0$ is an identity element.

Now, let $a,m \in G$ and $m$ be an inverse of $a$. Then,
$m*a=m+a=0 \Rightarrow m=-a$. But, $-a \notin G$. So, $a$ has no inverse.

Hence, $(G,*)$ is not group.

(ii) If $x+y \geq 1$, then $x*y=x+y-1$.

It's easy to prove that $*$ assosiative. Now, let $a,i \in G$ and $i$ be the inverse of $a$. Then, $i*a=i+a-1=a=a+i-1=a*i$. Its follows that $i=1$. But, $1 \notin G$. So, there's no an identity element of $a$.
It's follows that there's no inverse for $a$.

Hence, $(G*)$ is not group.

Comment: So what is your question???

Comment: It seems to me the definition is of one alleged group, where (i) and (ii) are both used to define the same operation.

Comment: ............ so?

Comment: The inverse of $x$ is $1-x$, because $x + (1-x) = 1$, so $x * (1-x) = 1-1 = 0$

Comment: @GEdgar is making the point is that this is not two questions (one to prove it for operation (i), then one to prove it for operation (ii) ) - it's one operation, which just has been expressed in two parts to ensure it can be evaluated for any x and y in G.  0.2 * 0.4 = 0.6, 0.2 * 0.9 = 0.1 etc.  0 is the identity. (1-x) is the inverse of x.  Messy to show associativity, but as this is basically modular arithmetic it must be doable.

Comment: I think you're missing cases with proving associativity.

Comment: Consider for example $0.4$ , $0.5$ and $0.6$. 
$$(0.4 * 0.5) *0.6 = (0.4 + 0.5)*0.6 = 0.9*0.6 = 1.5 - 1 = 0.5$$
and
$$0.4*(0.5*0.6) = 0.4 * (1.1-1) = 0.4 * 0.1 = 0.4 + 0.1 = 0.5$$
and there are alot more interactions to check.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are familiar with quotient groups, then you might want to argue that G is in fact similar to $(\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: $(G, *)$ looks like a circle to me, perhaps you want to take your intuition from there? Alternatively, perhaps you should view the set as $\{\exp(2 \pi i x) \mid 0 \leq x < 1\}$ and figure out what $*$ is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it's worth verifying that * is well-defined: because $0 \leq x, y  < 1$, either

$0 \leq x+y < 1$

or $1 \leq x+y < 2$ which means $0 \leq x+y-1 < 1$

so either way $0 \leq x*y < 1$ ensuring $x*y \in G$.

Existence of an identity and inverses are both straightforward:

[identity] If $x \in G$ then $0 \leq 0+x = x <1$ so $0 * x = x*0 = x$.

[inverse] If $x \in G$ then either $x=0$ and $0*0=0$ or...

$$0 < x <1$$ 
$$0 < 1-x <1$$
$$x+(1-x) = x+1-x = 1$$ 
$$x*(1-x) = x+(1-x)-1 =0$$
So every element has an inverse.

Finally for associativity, note that $x*y = x+y+n$ for some $n \in \lbrace 0,-1 \rbrace$.  Using the associativity (and commutativity) of addition:$$(a*b)*c = (a+b+n_1)*c = a+b+n_1+c+n_2 = a+b+c+(n_1+n_2) \space [A]$$
$$a*(b*c) = a*(b+c+n_3) = a+(b+c+n_3)+n_4 = a+b+c+(n_3+n_4) \space [B]$$
where each $n_i$ is an integer.

Because of what I set out at the top of this answer, we know that both [A] and [B] are in G, so $$0 \leq a+b+c+(n_1+n_2) < 1$$ and $$0 \leq a+b+c+(n_3+n_4) < 1.$$  Writing the latter as $$-1 < -a-b-c-(n_3+n_4) \leq 0$$ and adding $$-1 < (n_1+n_2) - (n_3+n_4) <1.$$ But as $(n_1+n_2) - (n_3+n_4)$ is an integer its only possible value is $0$.  This means $$(n_1+n_2) = (n_3+n_4)$$ so $$ a+b+c+(n_1+n_2) = a+b+c+(n_3+n_4)$$ so $$(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$$ as required.

In conclusion, $(G,*)$ is a group - the mistake in your solution was to consider separately the cases of $x+y$ being less than or greater than 1, as if there would be an identity $e_1$ satisfying $e_1 + y < 1$ and a different identity $e_2$ satisfying $e_2+y \geq 1$.  That's bound to fail because there is only one identity, namely $0$.

Comment: i still confused

Comment: @arnold - what's confusing you?  Do you understand what the operation * does?  It adds any two numbers which are of the form 0.xxx and only keeps the part of the answer to the right of the decimal point.  eg 0.24 * 0.35 = 0.59, but 0.601 + 0.712 = 1.313, so throw away the 1 and 0.601 * 0.712 = 0.313.  

So the operation is just like addition: it's associative, 0 is the identity, and the inverse of x is -x except that -x is not in the range [0,1], so we add 1 and say the inverse is 1-x: eg 0.2 + 0.8 = 1.0, throw away the 1, 0.2 * 0.8 = 0;
0.59 + 0.41 = 1.00, throw away the 1, 0.59 * 0.41 = 0

Comment: i'm confused on inverse argument

Comment: oh, got it. thanks

Comment: If $0 < x < 1$ then $x \in G$ and $(1-x) \in G$.  What is $x * (1-x)$ ?

Comment: $x * (1-x) = 0$ ?

Comment: Exactly, so that shows (1-x) is the inverse of x.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Define $\{x\} := x - \lfloor x\rfloor$, $x\in\mathbb R$, where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function. Prove that $\{x+y\} = \{x\}*\{y\}$. Observe that for $x\in [0,1)$ we have $\{x\} = x$.

1. $(x*y)*z = (\{x\}*\{y\})*\{z\} = \{x+y\}*\{z\} = \{(x+y)+z\}=\ldots =x*(y*z),$
2. $x*0 = \{x\}*\{0\} = \{x+0\} = \{x\} = x$, $0*x=\{0\}*\{x\}=\ldots = x$,
3. If $x = 0$, then $0*0 = 0$. If $x\neq 0$, then $0 = \{0\} = \{x +(-x)\} = \{x\} * \{-x\} = \{x\}*\{1-x\} = x*(1-x)$,
4. $x*y = \{x\}*\{y\} = \{x+y\} = \{y+x\} =  \{y\}*\{x\} = y*x.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Consider $\mathbb{R}$ under addition (clearly a group), and then quotient out by the integers to get $\mathbb{R/Z}$. Again, this is a group, and indeed is the group you are looking at here. So focus on this quotient group and work out what the operation should be, and prove that it is the operation you have here.